# ServiceStack and SignalR together in same project

Tags: asp.net, servicestack, signalr

It is somewhat trivial question, but I am using SignalR and ServiceStack in single Asp.Net host application.

Means, it is simple Asp.Net blank application, ServiceStack is running on `/` and it is showing default page using Razor. Running perfectly.

Now, I added SignalR asp.net host. Added startup class and created hub to listen and broadcast chat message.

I have wrote client code in default page only. Now, things are working fine. Means, API and SignalR are both running on local machine.

Now, the question is, is this the right way of doing things? Means, are there two different processes hitting IIS. Or is there any way I can chain process to single process.

Or even part of ServiceStack API I can make real-time.

Please let me know if any further information is required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes its possible, but you cannot run ServiceStack on Owin at the moment (as far as I know)

So you need to run ServiceStack in a specific location.

```
<location path="ssapi">

  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*" type="ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*"/>
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add path="*" name="ServiceStack.Factory" type="ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>

</location>
```

You may need to remove the handlers for owin/signalr stuff from the location too.

Alternatively you can setup SignalR on a specific path and remove ServiceStack from that path.

i.e

```
<location path="signalr">

  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <remove type="ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" />
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ServiceStack.Factory" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>

</location>
```

Answer (score 2):

I know the question focused on `SignalR`, but `ServiceStack` added support for [Server-Sent Events](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/) in [v4.0.31](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Server-Events).  Basicaly, this is a very long-lived HTTP request that streams to the client, allowing for real-time server "push"

This feature is supported by most modern browsers, and [polyfills](https://github.com/Yaffle/EventSource) can be used to support IE back to 8.  ServiceStack also provides a [C# client](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/C%23-Server-Events-Client).

Comment: The question was specifically about SignalR however.